# WordPress – Inserting a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to insert the following function in wordpress but it doesn't seem to work whereas the same function works in fiddle.

jQuery

```
 $(function(){
    $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
        var $lis = $('.photo').hide();
        //For each one checked 
        $('input:checked').each(function() {
                $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
        });
    });
  });
```

I've placed the following code in my page template in wordpress and it doesn't seem to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function($){
    $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
        var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
        //For each one checked
        $('input:checked').each(function() {
                $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you have added a reference of `jQuery library` in your `WordPress template`

Comment: Have you got any error on browser console?

Comment: no error and the script does not seem to appear when i inspect the element. Link to the website is [here](http://hbz.dev.mosaic.co.ke/?page_id=2)

Comment: You should use `.on()` instead of `.delegate()` if you're using newer versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few errors in your code.

1. `$('.results > li')` return empty because there are no `.results > li` elements
2. in `Flower` check box you have put `flower` for `rel` and in `div` you have used `flowers`

You need to select the `div` containers for `image`, Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
        var $div = $('div.photo').hide();
        $('input:checked').each(function() {
            $div.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
        });
    });
});
```